# How to log all incoming messages from Akka (Java)

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

In Scala you can wrap the receive function with a LoggingReceive. How do you achieve the same from the Java API?

```
def receive = {
  LoggingReceive {
    case x ⇒ // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M2/java/logging.html ?

Comment: I read the doc page but I think it only covers manual logging. From http://akka.io/faq/ "akka.actor.debug.receive will log all messages sent to an actor if that actors receive method is a LoggingReceive". But I couldn't figure out how to apply LoggingReceive in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Scala API has the `LoggingReceive` decorator because a partial function literal makes it awkward to express something to be done in all cases (like this logging).

In Java you don’t have this problem because your `onReceive` method is always called, and you can put a logging statement at the top to see all messages which are received by the actor. As an added bonus you get to decide at which level to log them ;-)

If you want to make your logging conditional on the config setting `akka.actor.debug.receive` (just as for Scala), then you can say for example

```
if (getContext().system().settings().AddLoggingReceive())
  log.debug("received message of type {}", msg.getClass());
```