# Log all messages in Akka without modifying all receive methods

Tags: scala, logging, akka, message

I want to log all received messages to all actors in my Akka app.
There is a config `akka.actor.debug.receive` that will log all messages sent to an actor if that actors receive method is a `LoggingReceive`.

According to http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/additional/faq.html it means wrapping all receive methods with `LoggingReceive` as in [How to log all incoming messages from Akka (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000843/how-to-log-all-incoming-messages-from-akka-java)

```
def receive = {
  LoggingReceive {
    case x ⇒ // do something
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this implicitly, or by config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you should very easily be able to do something like this:

```
trait LoggingReceiveActor extends Actor{

  def receive = LoggingReceive(loggedReceive)

  def loggedReceive:Receive
}

class MyActor extends LoggingReceiveActor{

  def loggedReceive = {
    case _ => 
  }
}
```

Any actor that inherits from `LoggingReceiveActor` now has to provide an impl for `loggingReceive` and if you do that, then when debug logging is enabled then this kind of actor will log the messages received.

Comment: Still have to modify all actors. Although a simple find-and-replace will do. I thought that seeing all messages would be a great way for debugging... is there some more convenient way to see what's going on?